# How can I get list of news_id from manytomanyfield table in django?

Tags: mysql, django

```
class news(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(source, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    headlines = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    site = models.URLField(null=True)
    story = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    datetime = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='favourite', blank=True)

-----------------
news_favourite table has id, news_id, user_id
---- -------------
```

I want to perform query like

```
select news_id from news_favourite where user_id= 1
```

(or it can be any user_id).

Comment: `news.objects.filter(favourite=current_user)`

Comment: Or if you want only `news_id` then you can use this `news.objects.filter(favourite=current_user).values_list('id', flat=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django [QuerySet.Filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) for this.

For example, for your case:

```
NewsFavourite.objects.filter(user_id=1).news
```

This will return News queryset.